# tradingview newest price history problem while using + in formula

Tags: pine-script

I know + symbol adds stocks with prices x and y on tradingview and charts price data x+y. Say,
x started trading at 2015,
y started trading at 2018.

The problem is, using x+y (no script yet, only typing in search bar) on tradingview, I get a chart starting at 2018. But I want that it starts at 2015 (assuming the price of y at that time frame as 0, I mean from 2015 to 2018).

In other words, I want to draw one single chart for which 2015-1018 timeline includes price of x only, and 2018 - onwards sketches the simple summation price x+y. How can I do that? Thanks in advance pine-masters, cheers..